# How to show records which does not contain a character or a number?

Tags: regex, hadoop, impala

I want to get all rows where a field contacts a value which is not a character or a string. I have been looking at regexp for this, but there may be a better way.

For example:
select regexp_like('abc123=', '[a-zA-Z0-9]') would return false

select regexp_like('abc123', '[a-zA-Z0-9]') would return true

currently, both the above return true, because they both contain a character and number, but I need the one with = in to return false.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you need `'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$'` - only match if the whole string contains letters or digits.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Solved!